# AWS S3 access point iam policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-access-points

Let's say I have the following AWS S3 access point:

`arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:123456789012:accesspoint/test-bucket1`

I need to add this ARN to an IAM policy so that my application, running in AWS with the respective IAM role, will be able to access the objects in the bucket.

Currently, my IAM inline policy contains the following line:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:123456789012:accesspoint/test-bucket1"`

Is it possible to add a wildcard character to this ARN in the IAM inline policy, like the example below?

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:us-west-2:123456789012:accesspoint/test*"`

Will the above configuration work? I have multiple buckets that I need to access, but I don't want to explicitly add each of them to the IAM inline policy. However, all of my access points share the same prefix "test," followed by "-bucket number."